# SQL Server 2019 Logs - Polybase

Tags: registry, sql-server-2019, polybase

I have a windows SQL Server 2019 RTM-CU8 Enterprise edition instance.
On restart, the logs report missing a registry key for Polybase, which was never installed and the services do not exist. Grateful for advice on suppressing this alert.
Example message:
Unable to retrieve registry value 'NodeRole' from Windows registry key 'Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.DW\Polybase\Configuration': (null).
SQL SERVERPROPERTY ('IsPolyBaseInstalled') shows that it is not installed.
Thank you.
Chris

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar error while I am trying to add a service account to the SQL Agent Service and start the service. Issue is fixed after I added the service account to the Windows server local admin group.